# How to tell which part of code should be inside a function?

Tags: python, function

I'm having a problem understanding which part of my code belongs to a funtions and which does not. My code is messy and I know I need to use functions to clean it up.
The code below is a console game whereby a computer generates a random integer between 1 and 100 and the user user guesses that number with a limited number of guesses.eg. 5 for hard. 10 for easy.

How can I use funtions in this code?

```
#TODO 1: Generate a random number between 1 and 100
import random

GUESS = random.randint(1, 100)
#TODO 2: Print the guess(,for debugging)


#TODO 3: Choose the difficulty("easy" or "hard")
difficulty = input("Choose a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard': ")
#TODO 4: Loop 5 times if the user typed 'hard' or 10 times if the user typed 'easy'

if difficulty == "hard":
  try:
    #TODO 4.1: User inputs the guesses the random number
    print("You have 5 attempts remaining to guess the number.")
    guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
    #TODO 4.2: Compare the guess and the random number
    if guess == GUESS:
      print(f"{guess} is the correct guess")
    elif guess > GUESS:
      print(f"{guess} is too high")
      #Count dowm
      for _ in range(5, 1, -1):
        print(f"You have {_-1} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
        guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
        if guess == GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is the correct guess")
          break
        elif guess > GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is too high")
        elif guess < GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is too low")

    elif guess < GUESS:
      print(f"{guess} is too low")
      #Count dowm
      for _ in range(5, 1, -1):
        print(f"You have {_-1} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
        guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
        if guess == GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is the correct guess")
          break
        elif guess > GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is too high")
        elif guess < GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is too low")
  except ValueError:
    print("Please input a number")

elif difficulty == "easy":
  #TODO 4.1: User inputs the guesses the random number
  try: 
    print("You have 10 attempts remaining to guess the number.")
    guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
    #TODO 4.2: Compare the guess and the random number
    if guess == GUESS:
      print(f"{guess} is the correct guess")
    elif guess > GUESS:
      print(f"{guess} is too high")
      #Count dowm
      for _ in range(10, 1, -1):
        print(f"You have {_-1} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
        guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
        if guess == GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is the correct guess")
          break
        elif guess > GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is too high")
        elif guess < GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is too low")

    elif guess < GUESS:
      print(f"{guess} is too low")
      #Count dowm
      for _ in range(10, 1, -1):
        print(f"You have {_-1} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
        guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
        if guess == GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is the correct guess")
          break
        elif guess > GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is too high")
        elif guess < GUESS:
          print(f"{guess} is too low")
  #I probably have to use exceptions
  #So im going to do a google search real quick
  #value errors
  except ValueError:
      print("Please input a number")
```

Comment: All of it should be in a function, apart from the import

Comment: The general concept is that when you have repeated code, it should be in a function.

Comment: The general concept is that when you have isolated functionality, it should be in a function + what @iced said.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, here's an example of one function that might be useful:

```
function CheckGuess (INTEGER guess, INTEGER answer) returns an STRING

   if guess > answer
      return "too high"

   if guess < answer
      return "too low"

   else
      return "exactly"
```

Now, keeping in mind that a function accepts 0 or more inputs and always returns single output, and that output should always be the same, given the same input, lets see how this can be used as a functional object.

```
if CheckGuess(7, 10) != "exactly"
   guesses = guesses - 1;
```

This is only one way of dozens that could be useful.  Hope this helps!

Comment: In math,  a function is expected to map the input to the output each time the same way, but in programming if my "function" returns a random something or always returns nothing at all, it will still be called a "function".

Comment: This is only true for **pure** functions.

Comment: Not sure that pseudo-code is particularly helpful. Python is syntactically essentially the perfect pseudo-code. Why not just include draft code in Python if that is the language in question?

Answer (score 0):

this could work, though i might have missed some functionality.:

```
def prompt(prompt):
 prompt(input)
def guessing_game:
 num_to_guess = random.randint(1,100)
 while number_of_guesses > 0:
 os.system("cls")
 guessed_number = prompt("guess between 1 and 100")
 if gessed_number == num_to_guess:
   os.system("cls")
   number_of_guesses = 0
   print("you got it!")
 else:
  if number_guessed < num_to_guess:
   os.system("cls")
   print("to low...")
   number_of_guesses =- 1
  else:
   os.system("cls")
   print("too high...")
   number_of_guesses =- 1
 if number_of_guesses == 0:
  print("you lost...")
  quit()
```

if this dosent work, check for typos.